# How to import music file from iphone music library to iPhone App

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios4

In MY iPhone App I am able to browse iphone Music Library
even I am importing media **file name** to my app music file list 
but  while running app next time i am not getting media file name which I imported previously

In My App i am importing songs from one folder "MusicSampler"  which is in my APP Folder now On buttonclick I am opening iPod music Library and selecting song (Using mediaPicker) which is added to my  song list at buttom, now next time when i am opening my App it loads the all songs from "musicSampler" folder but this time the new added songs previously  from iPod-Library are not showing

what I should do to save imported song from iPod music library to my iphone app( either by adding music file to my "MusicSampler" or something else)

Please Help and Suggest

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example:

http://www.subfurther.com/blog/2010/07/19/from-iphone-media-library-to-pcm-samples-in-dozens-of-confounding-potentially-lossy-steps/

In sum, you should use CoreAudio or AV Foundation to save mp3 from iPhone Media Library.

I hope that it helps you.

Comment: Skip to the bottom of that blog post for an updated, simpler version from the same author.

Answer (score 1):

OPEN Music Library of Phone

```
 MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];
    mediaPicker.delegate = self;
    mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = YES;
   [self presentViewController:mediaPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Delegate are

```
- (void)mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection
 {
   [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    MPMediaItem *item = [mediaItemCollection representativeItem];
    player=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[item     valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL] error:nil];
   [player play];
 }

- (void)mediaPickerDidCancel:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker {

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: This controller, in some cases takes a long time to be displayed. Any idea?